# Passing data from IONIC input to the controller

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ionic-framework

I am writing simple application where I am trying to pass the data from the IONIC form into the json file using MVC pattern. 
I am struggling with passing those data from the form.
I am using IONIC, JavaScript, NodeJS/ExpressJs.

This is my html form:

```html
<ion-content>
    <ion-header translucent>
        <ion-toolbar color="primary">
            <ion-title>Add a bug</ion-title>
        </ion-toolbar>
    </ion-header>
        <form class="bug-form" action="/add-bug" method="POST">
             <ion-item>
                <ion-label position="fixed">Bug title</ion-label>
                <ion-input id="name"></ion-input>
            </ion-item>
            <ion-item>
                <ion-label position="fixed">Bug description</ion-label>
                <ion-input id="desc"></ion-input>
            </ion-item>
            <ion-item>
                <ion-label position="fixed">Date</ion-label>
                <ion-input id="date" type="date"></ion-input>
            </ion-item>
            <ion-item>
                <ion-label position="fixed">Assigned to</ion-label>
                <ion-input id="assignedTo"></ion-input>
            </ion-item>
            <ion-item>
                <ion-label position="fixed">Assigned by</ion-label>
                <ion-input id="assignedBy"></ion-input>
            </ion-item>
                <ion-button type="submit" color="primary">Submit</ion-button>
                <ion-button href="view-bug" color="warning">Cancle</ion-button>
        </form>
</ion-content>
```

The code attached in routes.js:

```js
  
router.post('/add-bug', bugController.postAddBug);
```

And finally, my post request in the controller:

```js
exports.postAddBug = (req, res, next) =>{
    let name = document.getElementById('name');
    const bugs = new Bug(
        req.body.name,
        req.body.desc,
        req.body.date,
        req.body.assignedTo,
        req.body.assignedBy
    );
    console.log(bugs);
    bugs.save();
    res.redirect('/view-bug');
};
```

Apparently, I am trying to pass the data in wrong way, because all the fields are undefined.

Comment: try adding `name` attributes to your field.

Comment: which ionic version?

Comment: @ArunSelin, 5.4.4. Problem is sorted tho! :)

Comment: cool. If it is Ionic, you can define a ControllerClass and use ngModel construct to directly wire these form values to the class..right?